# Webserver from linux(debian) sends data to an Ip in a network

Tags: php, c, linux, sockets

[image]

Hi,

From the image above, I have a webserver a linux machine and client/device.. Now i need for this 3 to communicate. The webserver sends data to an ip address(client/device) based on button pressed on the webpage. but before the data is sent, the data must first access the linux machine, the machine then sends the data down to the device which then the device reads the data and act based on the command sent.. then the device sends back data to the linux machine which then the linux machine sends it to the webserver for ack'd. meaning data is received by the device without any problems.

1. Php is for the webserver. Now how will php sends data to an ip adress.
2. The linux machine handles all requests and sends everything down to the device and when the device got the data it will send a data to linux machine which then machine sends an ok to the webserver that the data arrived succesfully.(I read about socket programming and i think of creating an application that reads requests.) or if you have any idea how can i do this?.
3. How can the device read a data sent by the webserver?..

Thanks,

**EDIT:** The device is not connected to the linux machine. the device is only connnected via the ethernet cable.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more details about the device? Does it support any standard protocols (maybe Telnet? HTTP?), and whether it provides streams of data (like audio/video), or just short responses to queries?

Comment: Sorry about that...well the device is arduino+ethernet shield on it.. a stepper driver is connected to it for which the stepper motors are connnected.. the stepper moves depending on the data sent by the controller/linux machine to the arduino+ethernet shield. I plan to use the client on this site http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm which i can use to send data to the ip of arduino ethernet. The arduino ethernet then reads it by doing client.read().. for the browser to read data on linux i plan on using pipes on php. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If you use TCP sockets, then sending back data from the Arduino ethernet shield is as simple as `client.write()`. The TCP connection is bidirectional, all you need to be aware of is to avoid the situation when both wait for the other to send data. You can contact the Arduino directly from PHP, too, if you use PHP `fsockopen()` to open the connection to the Arduino separately each time the user presses a button.

Comment: Yes thank you but i really need first to access linux before everything will be sent.. so in php i'll just do an ipc inside linux using pipes. The linux will just act like a broker to php and the device.. which do you prefer i use in the link i provided for linux will it be server or client and for the arduino it will be client?.. thank you.. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the topmost machine 'Server', the middle machine 'Controller' and the bottom machine 'Device'. It does not matter if the device is a peripheral (say, USB or serial device), or a computer.

The first task is to get the Controller to query the Device. The best way to do this really depends on the Device. If you consider things like USB audio/video devices, they need to be tuned, then they send a continuous stream of data. Things like temperature or humidity sensors are told to do a measurement, then they respond with data.

Usually you write the required functions into a small library, and verify it works using command line tools. In some cases the library may not be necessary, for example if the Device is already supported by the kernel in Controller, and the information is trivially available. (For example, consider the temperature sensors in hard drives: if Device(s) are hard disks, then Controller can simply use the command `hddtemp /dev/sda` to get the temperature of the `/dev/sda` (first SATA/ATA/SCSI hard disk). I'd expect the end user to be able to pick which hard disks she is interested in, so that choice would have to flow from Server to Controller.)

Next, you write a service that will run on the Controller. This service will incorporate the library functions already written and tested, so it can easily access the Device. (This way you *know* the Controller-Device communication works, and don't need to worry about it. One thing at a time.)

There are many different designs for the service, from plain TCP/IP or UDP/IP sockets to Remote Procedure Calls (RPC), to high-level protocols like HTTP. In recent years, the last, using HTTP, has become more and more common, with responses being XML, plain text, or binary media (usually images). The idea is to have the service be basically just another web server that can access the Device directly. Security is simpler, because it does not need to be world-accessible: it can very well only answer to requests coming from the Server only. I've written such services using basic shell scripting (Bash), PHP (both PHP-CGI and command-line PHP, PHP-CLI), and C, among others. The best choice depends on the details, really. I personally prefer either a simple text-based TCP/IP socket, or HTTP.

On the Server, you can write a PHP page, that connects to Controller, requesting whatever it wants to request (usually depends on user data, first checked for sanity and safety, of course). PHP has easy built-in facilities for doing both HTTP requests and connecting using raw TCP/IP, so it suits quite well for this. If HTTP protocol wrappers are enabled, then it is just `$handle = fopen("http://192.168.x.x/myservice?param1=" . urlencode($param1) . "&param2=" . urlencode($param2), "r+b");`. To get a socket connection, you use the `fsockopen()` function instead. (For details, see [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [http wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), and [`fsockopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) at the [PHP Function Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php) at [www.php.net](http://www.php.net/).)

In practice the PHP page code first creates a connection to the Controller. Then it sends a request, containing the relevant sanitized commands/parameters received from the end user. Then it waits for the Controller to respond with the results (by simply reading the response), then closes the connection. The response should contain all the data needed, so the PHP page is free to construct the page to the end user.

None of this is really difficult, but there is a lot to do. I've found the Controller-Device communication to require the most work; after that is done, the rest has always been quite straightforward.

If you can provide more details what the Controller-Device connection is, what kind of data (text? numbers? images? a lot of binary data?) the Device provides, and what kind of parameters/commands (just "one result, please?", basic commands like "move up", "where are you?") do you expect you need to send to the Controller/Device, I could perhaps be more specific.

Also, are you limited to PHP, or would you be comfortable writing the Controller service using C? I've found that to be a very good combination myself.

---

Edited to add:

In a nutshell, the three points can be answered as follows:

1. Either using `fopen("http://ip.add.re.ss:port/", "r+b");` if using the HTTP protocol and PHP is configured to allow http wrappers (they usually are), or using `fsockopen()`. See the PHP documentation linked above for details.
2. With an IP-connected Device, Controller is basically a relay or translator. Usually this means a daemon running on Controller, managing incoming requests from Server (or Servers), and responses from Device (or Devices). This is more common when there are a varying number of Devices, and/or more than one interface is needed. In practice, the Controller runs a daemon just like described above, except the protocols may be standard or simple enough so there is no need to write a library.
3. The PHP running on the Server must contain the request details (exactly what is desired) to the Controller. The Controller must pass them on to the Device. If the Controller provides a http URL for the PHPs on the server connect to, it can parse the query parameters, and translate them into a format the Device understands.
   One particular issue in practice is to handle concurrent accesses. There is usually only a single connection from Controller to Device, but more than one PHP might connect to the Controller simultaneously. So there is some book-keeping involved.
   In some cases the Device provides a continuous stream of data (or regular updates of data) to the Controller, and the Controller simply keeps tabs on it. When a PHP running on the Server queries something from the Controller, the Controller simply looks up the latest data (without contacting the Device at all, just receiving the data as normal), and responds with it. Here, it is common to include a timestamp, or better yet, the age of the data, in the response from Controller to Server.

You really should add some details to your question. (I suspect the downvote is due to lack of details.) You don't need to tell us the exact make and model of the Device, only whether it is a receiver (TV? radio? weather station?) or a sensor cluster or a door lock, and if you know any details on the communications protocols (which ones)? Thus far, we only know it uses IP. That does not help at all, just about *everything* uses IP nowadays. This is also why my answer is so vague; I'd like to be more precise, but you do not provide enough information for me to do so.

Comment: Wow thanks for the very long answer... I now have something on my mind... I forgot to mention that the client/device is not connected to the linux machine my bad for that.. it is only connected via the ethernet cable.. so the device is separate to the linux machine.. So if turns like that then it's straightforware.. webserver -> device it will no longer access the controller.. how can i make it possible that the controller detects the device without it being attached to it? it only has ip which will i be using to control it. thanks again.

Comment: @demic0de: The same principle applies, even if Device is connected to Controller via Ethernet. (In that case, often Server and Controller are the same machine, but they don't have to be.) You don't necessarily need a Controller service, if the Device allows multiple concurrent accesses, or if you prevent that in the PHP on Server, and the Device responds in reasonable time. Detecting the Device is just probing: basically try a connection, and see if it works. (There are also protocols for local network device discovery, but it really depends on the Device, what it supports.)

Comment: Thank you the device is arduino ethernet.. The arduino ethernet must first send data to the controller for it to be recognized. the controller can then control it. but i don't know how to do it in arduino. i know how can i send data from linux to arduino ethernet via sockets but i don't know how to do it in arduino ethernet..thanks,